# Number, hover (etc) effect not work after Ajax Load More

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

I'm using Drupal 7 and get my content with View module on page. And my pager Views Load More module. And my thumbnail effect hover, shadow etc. Image hover using this code:

```
var hoverImg = '<div class="hoverimg"></div>';

$(".thumb").each(function(){
    $(this).children("div").each(function(){
        $(this).find("a").append(hoverImg);
    });
});

$(".thumb div").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".hoverimg").animate({ opacity: 'toggle' });
});

$(".thumb").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("div").each(function(){
        $(this).find(".shadow").fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

And getting number on my current thumbnail. This code:

```
var c = '';
var d = '';
$('.view-content div.views-row').each(function(){
    c = 0;
    d = 0;
    var i = 1;
    d = $(this).find('.thumbimg').length;
    $(this).find('.thumbimg').each(function(){
        sayi=i++;
        $(this).append('<div class="img_no">0'+sayi+'</div>');
    });
});
```

Everything is OK. All effects on start page. But when click Load More button, my effects can't work another page.

How do i solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it stops working is due to the hover function (and your other scripts/functions) only works on existing elements. So if you add something with ajax, it wont apply to that unless you reload the script after the ajax load.

Another option is to use live() or on() (for the hover part. On is the new version of live, added in jQuery 1.7).
Live and on listens for any existing or future elements.

A live script would look something like this:

```
            $(".yourElement").live({
                mouseenter:
                function () {
                    // Do something
                },
                mouseleave:
                function () {
                    // Do something
                },
                mousemove:
                function () {
                   // Do something
                }
            });
```